# How can I loop through the elements of an angularjs drop down menu using python

Tags: python, angularjs, web-scraping

This is the Html code for the drop down menu with list of cities:

[image: Code of Cities]

I just want to loop through all of the cities using python. BTW I am trying to create a web scraper, and have no api for the site :(

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io. Selenium might help.

Comment: I am using selenium but just new to it so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to click the drop down and once it populates grab the drop down city lists. Can you share the website link?                                                      https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: Usually with selenium, selecting the dropdown, waiting a few seconds, and re-loading the html tree is the way to go

Comment: The website link has sensitive data so I can't really allow access to the page, but is there not a way to loop through the elements besides from using selenium to click and then move to the next city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone with the same issue you can just use the xpath and find the index pattern.